# Single Sign On Application Cookie Issue

Tags: cookies, asp.net-membership, single-sign-on

Hi All 
I am working on a single sign on system which a load of other web applications will use as its membership provider. I currently have the system up and running in ASP.NET MVC and everything works well, users can log into an application once and have access to all the other apps through that login cookie. 
 
The problem is that users dont all have access to the same apps, this is currently handled at login and if they dont have access to the app they are denied. However with the cookie being set automatically by asp membership, if they do login to an application they have access to they are then given access to all the other apps via the cookie, including the ones they dont have access to. 
Any ideas on how to fix this? Ideally I want the cookie to remain as part of the process as I like the idea of a user logging in just once to access all the apps they have. Ideally the applications will maintain the login details but check a webservice if those details have access to that app? I wont have access to the individual applications (they all use standard out the box asp membership, only the web config is altered to point to my system) and all this must be managed by the Signle Sign On area.

Many thanks in advance to those who contribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting the names differently for each of the apps that use the membership system?

Comment: I was just telling you on gchat that id fixed it and how I did it and you answer the question on here, this is a disgraceful attempt at getting stackoverflow points. I love it. LAD.

Comment: The way it was fixed was to set different names for the cookies on each application. Then when the user logs into the central hub the system checks the database for the applications the user has access to and creates the cookies for those names. This doesnt completely meet the original spec, as each application should do this as well as the central area but I have spoken with the client and altered the spec slightly. Was a fairly simple solution once the spec changed!